# For the general form of a characteristic polynomial what is the trace squared of matrix A mean?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I've seen the formula written as the following:

$$ Characteristic Polynomial = −λ^3+ tr(A)λ^2+(tr(A)^2−tr(A^2))λ+det(A)$$

Although sometimes I've seen $tr(A)^2$ written as $tr^2(A)$. What does that mean and how do I compute it?

For the given matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 2\\2 & 2 & -1\\2&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$

Its characteristic polynomial is $-\lambda^3 +3\lambda^2+9\lambda-27$

If the $tr(A^2) = 27$ then what is the $tr(A)^2$ in order to get $9\lambda$? Or have I made a mistake with the first part?

Comment: I think you have lost a factor of $1/2$. (Check your formula for the characteristic polynomial on a diagonal matrix.)

Comment: Four your matrix, $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ is $2+2-1=3$. Hence, $\operatorname{tr}(A)^2=3^2=9$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but what about the $-tr(A^2)$ term? Then it becomes $-18$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If I'm missing a factor of $1/2$ I'm not sure where it would go because the $-tr(A)^2$ term would make the final result $-9$ instead of $-18$. Still the wrong sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic equation for the matrix $\textbf{A}$ is defined as

$$\lambda^3-\lambda^2\text{tr}(\textbf{A})+\dfrac{1}{2}\lambda\big[ \text{tr}^2(\textbf{A}) - \text{tr}(\textbf{A}^2)  \big] - \text{det}\textbf{A} = 0$$

For the given matrix, $\text{tr}(\textbf{A})=3$ and $\text{tr}(\textbf{A}^2)=27$ therefore $\frac{1}{2}\big[ \text{tr}^2(\textbf{A}) - \text{tr}(\textbf{A}^2)  \big] = -9$. We know $\text{det}\textbf{A}=-27$ and finally he characterestic equation is

$$\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-9\lambda+27 = 0$$